# easiest way to develop a demo restful web service

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I'm preparing a workshop on single web page development (you know, javascript, jquery, backbone) for beginner, and I though it would be nice to develop a basic restful web service, but I'd like something quick and basic to get started

Ideally, I'm looking for something like this:

- define some sql statements to create a few tables with relations and populate them
- define the endpoints and the mappings to the sql entities
- off you go

other desired features

- multi platform
- extensible (to add errors and custom validations)
- easy programming (perhaps something with python, ruby, groovy)
- authentication out of the box (oauth would be great)
- cors support (to upload it somewhere and then just use it)

In other words, I'm looking for a quick and nice way to build a basic restful web service. If that can be the foundation of a production web service, that would be awesome

What framework or toolkit would you advice me to research?

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have used free version of SoapUI have a look at this link see if it is any good for you http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/mocking-rest-services.html

Answer (score 1):

This is some python project that looks a lot like what I'm looking for

https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve

I'll give it a try to see how it goes

and here's a presentation: https://speakerdeck.com/nicola/developing-restful-web-apis-with-python-flask-and-mongodb